# Reference Error : document is not defined in nativescript-vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nativescript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
while(elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].classList.remove('active');
}
$event.target.classList.add('active');
```

It shows document not defined error

Answer (score 3):

you're using web technologies in a native mobile application. The best way to get the id of the element is by giving your element a ref and doing something like this:

```
 const textField = this.$refs.groceryTextField.nativeView
```

There are lots of good examples in this repo: https://github.com/tralves/groceries-ns-vue/ and you can also checkout the marketplace for more code samples: [market.nativescript.org](http://market.nativescript.org).

Comment: How to add/remove css class to that ref ?

Comment: You could do this right in the markup of the template: 

:class="{'visible': elements.length > 0}"